# Elasticsearch - missing data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have been planning to use ELK for our production environment and seems to be running into a weird problem -

the problem is that while loading a sample of the production log file I realized that there is a huge mismatch in the number of events being published by Filebeat and what we see in kibana. My first doubt was on filebeat but i could verify that all the events were successfully received in logstash.

I also checked logstash (by enabling debug mode ) and could see all the events were received and processed (i am using the following filters `date` , `json` ) and i could see them getting processed successfully

but when i do a search in kibana I only get to see the percent of the number of logs being actually published (e.g. only 16000 out of 350K). No exception or error in either logstash or elasticsearch logs.

I have tried zapping the entire data by doing the following so far :

1. Stopped all processes for ES, Logstash and kibana.
2. Deleted all the index files, cleared the cache , deleted mappings
3. stopped filebeat, deleted registry files (since its running in windows)
4. Restarted elasticsearch, logstash and filebeat (in that order)

but same results. i get only 2 out of 8 records (in the shortened file) and even less when i use the full file

i tried increasing the time windows in kibana to 10 years (:)) to see if they are being pushed to the wrong year but got nothing

I have read almost all threads related to the missing data but nothing seems to work.

any pointers would help !

Comment: Anything interesting in the elasticsearch logs? Also I don't think Kibana is the issue here, but maybe try querying Elasticsearch directly just to confirm.

Comment: Have gone thru the logs with a magnifying glass but not a hint anywhere. I am using two `json` filters with `skip_on_error => true` flag could that be an issue?

Comment: It could be -- sorry, I'm not very experienced with logstash. If there are no errors in the ES logs though (and your ES version is recent), and the data really isn't there, I would strongly suspect the problem is with logstash, not ES. Anyway, can you find an example log that didn't make it through, and try with just that one line? -- then in case it fails, you can update the question with exactly the example that fails, and probably someone familiar with logstash will be able to help.

Comment: For `skip_on_error => true`, it should not drop the records, according to the documentation. With `skip_on_error => true`, when the json parsing fails, the record does not receive a tag (by default `_jsonparsefailure`) and no error is logged. By default (`skip_on_error => false`), when the json parsing fails, the record does receive a tag (by default `_jsonparsefailure`) and an error is logged.

Comment: Yes that is my premise as well
I actually see that the records are getting processed but just not getting pushed to ES. Am evaluating the JSON filter again (by removing and then checking if it help).
Will keep posted on the results :)